# Unable to add Authorized redirect URI for OAuth 2.0 client

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, firebase-hosting

I'm setting up an OAuth client for a Firebase application on Firebase Hosting, and I'm trying to add an authorized redirect URI to the "Web client  (auto created by Google Service)" here:

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient

I'd like to add `https://my-project.web.app/serviceworker/redirect` but the update operation silently fails - loader just keeps spinning - and reports the following in the console:

```
Uncaught Proxy {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "ErrorResponse"}
```

and

```
Uncaught Error: Ch
```

I'd rather not post the specific domain here, but the strange thing is, I've been able to add it in another project, as a test, and I've also been able to add the `https://www.my-project.firebaseapp.com/serviceworker/redirect` address with no issues. And for what it's worth, the subdomain `https://www.my-project.web.app/serviceworker/redirect` was also fine. (Although it doesn't actually fix my issue)

So it seems to be a specific issue with this particular domain and in this particular project.

Posting here in the hopes that someone on Google's side has any more ideas, as I'm at a loss.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this would make a difference for this specific domain, but the issue resolved itself once I went through the "OAuth consent screen" setup.
So if you encounter this issue, I'd make sure everything's set up there first.